# Data modeling of Grandparent, Parent, and Child relationships in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design

Is it a bad practice to set a model (table) association between both parent and child AND grandparent and child?   For example, if I want to easily query a user's projects or a user's tasks, is the following setup recommended?  If so, is there a good way to ensure both foreign keys always point to the same user?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name

  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks
end


class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :status

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :tasks
end


class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :status

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :project
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with what you are trying to do, in fact rails has already predefined some association methods to help you.  Just a couple of modifications and you are good to go

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name

  has_many :projects
  has_many :tasks, through: :projects
end
```

By adding the `through: :projects` to your tasks now means you can access all of a users tasks like so

```
$user = User.first #or whatever
$user.tasks 
=> [AR array of all tasks]
```

You can play around with it in irb.  In addition you don't need `belongs_to :user` in your Task model.  It's already taken care of.

[Look at section 2.4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) for more details

EDIT:  I have made the assumption (based upon your description) that a task belongs to a project, and a project belongs_to a user, and that user's don't have tasks directly, but through projects.  If that was wrong, let me know and we'll figure it out from there.

Comment: Your assumption was correct.  I did not know about that use of has_many through.  I thought it was for many-to-many relationships only.  Thanks!